# Sort in SQL by compare method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, compare

Suppose I have the following situation in my database:
The first element is user ID, the second is some data and the last, mark of it.

```
1-1-1
1-2-2
1-3-4

2-4-1
2-2-1

3-1-5
3-3-1
3-2-5

4-2-2
4-1-1

5-4-1
5-6-2
```

How can I do some sort and return from SQL-query IDs which will be sorted by marks if data is in another ID of user.
Example: if I compare user’s data having the ID `1` with others, it must return the following:

```
4-2-2
4-1-1

2-4-1
2-2-1

3-1-5
3-3-1
3-2-5
```

So the sort will return data in the order: 4, 2, 3.

Then SORT!
I want to say in more detail:
See, please:

```
1-1-1
1-2-9
1-4-2

2-1-5
2-2-2
2-5-4

3-1-3
3-3-3
3-2-8
3-4-6 
3-6-10
```

**============= ============= 1 ============== ==============**
User with 2nd id:
1: (10-1) - (10-5) =    (4)  = 4;
2: (10-9) - (10-2) = ABS(-7) = 7;
3: next data what is in user 1 - absent in user 2, and we ease pass it;

User with 3rd id:
1: (10-1) - (10-3) =    (2)  = 2;
2: the next data's is absent in user with 3rt id;
3: (10-9) - (10-8) = ABS(-1) = 2;
4: (10-2) - (10-6) =    (4)  = 4; 
5: passed;

**============== ============= 2 ============== ==============**
Then me need count a result: 
So it will: 
User 2: COUNT = (4+7)   = 11;
User 3: COUNT = (2+2+4) =  8;
and delete this result on amount: 
User 2: COUNT = COUNT / 2 = 11/2 = 5.5;
User 3: COUNT = COUNT / 3 = 8/3  = 2.666666666666667;

**============== ============= 3 ============== ==============**

And in end:
I want see sort only that data, what first user don't have with sort by mark + result:
So, I will have next line:

From first user:
2-5-4
From second user: 
3-4-6
3-6-10 

Then sort by mark + result and **in the end we will have**:
1: 3-6-10, *cause: (10+2.666666666666667= 12.666666666666667)*
2: 2-5-4,  *cause: (4+5.5= 9.5)*
3: 3-3-3,  *cause: (3+2.666666666666667= 5.666666666666667)*

Comment: Can you better explain the rules for the comparison?

Comment: Ok, listen I have db-table with user id, name of fruits and their mark for every fruit! An user want to take other fruit what he never taste
but he want some else. Query must find users with most matched names of fruits and then compare it by mark... Then for every user set the most appropriate result, then sort this users by this result and return id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list of matching *users*:

```
select t.user, count(*) as NumMatches
from table t join
     table t1
     on t.data = t1.data and
        t.mark = t1.mark and
        t1.userid = 1 and
        t.userid <> 1
group by t.user;
```

To get their detail, we have to join that back in:

```
select tu.*
from (select t.user, count(*) as NumMatches
      from table t join
           table t1
           on t.data = t1.data and
              t.mark = t1.mark and
              t1.userid = 1 and
              t.userid <> 1
      group by t.user
     ) tu join
     table t
     on tu.user = t.user
order by t.NumMatches desc, t.user;
```

Comment: Thank You! But I have one more question - I want to make **more advanced sorting**, cause I dont right say my answer. 
So, you write next line: `t.mark = t1.mark and` I want change it!
**Please, see my post - I update it**

Comment: @serge . . . It is impolite to change a question after it has been answered.  If a post answers your question and you are so-inclined, you should accept and/or upvote it.  If you have a further question, ask another question.

Comment: sorry. THANK YOU! I can add one more question, Of course!

Comment: see please: [edited question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812902/sort-in-sql-by-compare-method-with-some-analysis)